# Is this Percentile Rank example conclusion in official document correct?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

As I read the [*Elastic Search 7.2 Percentile Ranks Aggregation*](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-rank-aggregation.html) and the example conclusion as

> From this information you can determine **you are hitting the 99% load time target** but **not quite hitting the 95% load time target**.

While the specification and result are actually

> Assume your data consists of website load times. You may have a service agreement that 95% of page loads completely within 500ms and 99% of page loads complete within 600ms.

```
   "aggregations": {
      "load_time_ranks": {
         "values" : {
            "500.0": 55.00000000000001,
            "600.0": 64.0
         }
      }
   }
```

I checked some math sites defining percentile rank, like

- [Percentiles, Percentile Rank & Percentile Range: Definition & Examples](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/percentiles-rank-range/)
- [Percentile Rank](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/percentile-rank.html)
- [Percentile Rank](http://davidmlane.com/hyperstat/A79766.html)
- [Percentile Rank Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile_rank)

And the conclusion in the official doc should be failed in both cases and it's wrong as I see it.

It should be something as follows to meet its final conclusion:

```
   "aggregations": {
      "load_time_ranks": {
         "values" : {
            "500.0": 94.00000000000001,
            "600.0": 99.9
         }
      }
   }
```

Any help will be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a wrong documentation caused by ES testing framework, you could check the details in this [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/45069) I started.